# unset a session then return its data

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I want to get a session and then return its data then unset it (or get a session and then unset it then return the data), I am doing 2 (header) redirects. after setting the session till getting the session.

but the problem is its not returning anything.

following is the class I am using:

class Session {

```
private $session_data1;


public function __construct() {

    session_start();  // starts session on all files at first...
}



public function set_session($session_name, $session_data) {

    return ($_SESSION[$session_name] = $session_data) ? true : false;
}


public function get_session($session_name) {

    return isset($_SESSION[$session_name]) ? $_SESSION[$session_name] : false;
}



public function get_session_once($session_name) {

    $this->session_data1 = $this->get_session($session_name);

    $this->unset_session($session_name);

    return $this->session_data1;
}



public function unset_session($session_name) {

    if (isset($_SESSION[$session_name])) {

        unset($_SESSION[$session_name]);
        // return true;
    }
}



public function destroy_all_session() {

    session_destroy();
}
```

}

$session = new Session();

I am using 'set_session()' to set a session and wanted to use 'get_session_once()' which will unset the session and then return the value of that session.

if I dont unset it in the method 'get_session_once()' then it works, like the following:

```
public function get_session_once($session_name) {

    $this->session_data1 = $this->get_session($session_name);

    // $this->unset_session($session_name);

    return $this->session_data1;
}
```

I am new in PHP, please help

Comment: Please update your code formatting; the way it appears now is quite confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this, and for me it's working.

```
<?

    $session = new Session();

    $session->set_session('Username', 'StackOverflow');

    echo $session->get_session_once('Username'); // echos 'StackOverflow'

    echo $session->get_session_once('Username'); // no echo

?>
```

This is still the same:

```
public function get_session_once($session_name) {

    $this->session_data1 = $this->get_session($session_name);

    $this->unset_session($session_name);

    return $this->session_data1;
}
```

Maybe the header redirect is the cause, it might be clear/delete the session.

Did you put **session_start()** at the start of every page?

Comment: Yes, you may noticed that I started session on the '__construct function' and I loaded this page first on every page. so there's that.
Thank you for your help